# How can I override Backend Fluid Templates?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

I want to extend the backend page layout partial `LanguageColumns` so that I can add some information in the marked spot (see screenshot snippet). I found that it should be possible according to this link: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79124-AllowOverwritingOfTemplatePathsInBackendTemplateView.html
However I cannot figure out how/where to add that code. I am using TYPO3 10.4.20

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned feature is only for custom modules and not to be meant to change existing backend modules.

One way which is often used, e.g. in EXT:yoast_seo, is the hook `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/db_layout.php']['drawHeaderHook']` of the `PageLayoutController`.

---

You can also manipulate the Toolbar by using the hook `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['Backend\Template\Components\ButtonBar']`. For inspiration you can checkout this code https://github.com/georgringer/page_speed/blob/feature/pagemodule/Classes/Hooks/ButtonBarHook.php (only in the branch *feature/pagemodule*  and only a PoC)

Comment: Thank you. I did it with the first option now, although it's not want I preferred :-)